# Can i use a variable from the GET_ method to fetch mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

im wondering if this can be done, or if is wrong:

i have a table in mysql wich contains this colums:

email_message | email_message_es | email_subject | email_subject_es

So i have this code:

```
$email_message = $_GET['langmess'];
$email_subject = $_GET['langsub'];

if ($payment == 'gateway1') {
        //Admin Email DATA
        $admin_mail     = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM email_template WHERE email_type = 'email_me' ");
        $admin_mailData = mysqli_fetch_array($admin_mail);
        //Variables
        $string         = $admin_mailData['$email_message'];
        $subjectmail    = $admin_mailData['$email_subject'];
        $pattern        = '/{(\w+)}/i';
        $replacement    = "$$1";
        $msnAdminbody   = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
        eval("\$msnAdminbody = \"<html><body> " . $msnAdminbody . " </body></html>\";");
```

This is just part of the code, but im not sure if i can use a variable to get the data from mysql, the idea is that the URL contains: http://mydomain/file.php?langmess=email_message_es&langsub=email_subject_es

or

http://mydomain/file.php?langmess=email_message&langsub=email_subject

And so, the email can be sent in the right language to the admin and to the user in the future.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, and im sorry for my english.

Comment: You can have multiple values in a `where` clause use an `and` or `or` to join them. Don't pass user data directly to your query. Use parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: you can use it sort of. Read ↑ the ↑ above ↑

Comment: Additionally a variable in single quotes is not a variable, it is the literal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have much to do with MySQL but the problem is this:

```
    $string         = $admin_mailData['$email_message'];
    $subjectmail    = $admin_mailData['$email_subject'];
```

With the single quotes, PHP looks for an index called literally '$email_message'. You need to remove the single quotes to retrieve the column named after the value of the variable.

```
    $string         = $admin_mailData[$email_message];
    $subjectmail    = $admin_mailData[$email_subject];
```

That doesn't solve all of the security issues in your code by the way. A safer way to do this is something like this:

```
$language_code = $_GET['lang'];

if ($payment == 'gateway1') {
    //Admin Email DATA
    $admin_mail     = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM email_template WHERE email_type = 'email_me' ");
    $admin_mailData = mysqli_fetch_array($admin_mail);
    //Variables

    switch($language_code)
    {
        case 'es':
            $string         = $admin_mailData['email_message_es'];
            $subjectmail    = $admin_mailData['email_subject_es'];
            break;
        default:
            $string         = $admin_mailData['email_message'];
            $subjectmail    = $admin_mailData['email_subject'];
            break;
    }
    $pattern        = '/{(\w+)}/i';
    $replacement    = "$$1";
    $msnAdminbody   = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

And the `eval()` is really unneccessary here and can be replaced with:

```
    $msnAdminbody = "<html><body> " . $msnAdminbody . " </body></html>";
```

Comment: This looks a lot better, the only problem is that i have an admin back-end site, where you can customize the email template depending of the language, and also you can add languages, so if a new language is generated the code will not work until i add a new language as you describe it, it can work for specified languages, but for costumers which can add languages, it doesn't, but your answer is right with my initial question, so thanks a lot, now i understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you have to use double quote instead single quote-> $admin_mailData["$email_message"].
But is is not good idea because client can easy modify $_GET variables and send empty mail.